# Zend: Form validation: value was not found in the haystack error

Tags: zend-framework

I have a form with 2 selects. Based on the value of the first select, it updates the values of the second select using AJAX. Doing this makes the form not being valid. So, I made the next change:

```
        $form=$this->getAddTaskForm(); //the form

        if(!$form->isValid($_POST)) {
            $values=$form->getValues();

            //get the options and put them in $options

                $assignMilestone=$form->getElement('assignedMilestone');
                $assignMilestone->addMultiOptions($options);

        }

        if($form->isValid($_POST)) {
               //save in the database
            }else {
               //redisplay the form
            }
```

Basically, I check if it is valid and it isn't if the user changed the value of the first select. I get the options that populated the second select and populate the form with them. Then I try to validate it again. However this doesn't work. Anybody can explain why? The same "value was not found in the haystack" is present.

Comment: Try `var_dump($options);` and then `var_dump($assignMilestone->getValue());` and see what results you get.  It must be that the array keys for `$options` does not contain the correct value that is set.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could try to deactivate the validator:

in your Form.php

```
$field = $this->createElement('select', 'fieldname');
$field->setLabel('Second SELECT');
$field->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
$this->addElement($field);
```

The third line will deactivate the validator and it should work.

Comment: I don't think that it's safe to just remove the validation, but if you decide to remove it you should at least change the validators. For example if you no longer check if the element is in the select array you need to make sure that the selected option is (at least) valid for your case... a "date" or "number" or "email" or whatever.

Comment: this option is very useful when mounting the select element dynamically with jquery.

Answer (score 14):

You can also disable the InArray validator using 'disable_inarray_validator' => true:

For example:

```
    $this->add( array(
        'name'     => 'progressStatus',
        'type'     => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'options' => array(
            'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
        ),

    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

Additionaly you should add you own InArray Validator in order to protect your db etc.

In Zend Framework 1 it looks like this:

```
$this->addElement('select', $name, array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Choose sth:',
            'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
            'multiOptions' => $nestedArrayOptions,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'InArray', true, array(
                        'haystack' => $flatArrayOptionsKeys,
                        'messages' => array(
                            Zend_Validate_InArray::NOT_IN_ARRAY => "Value not found"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
```

Where $nestedArrayOptions is you multiOptions and $flatArrayOptionsKeys contains you all keys.

Answer (score 2):

You may also add options to select element before checking for the form validation. This way you are insured the select value is in range.