# AJAX Adjust part of zend form based on select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a (Zend) form like this.

```
<form>
<select id=”select1”>
    <option value=”1”>choice 1</option>
    <option value=”2”>choice 2</option>
</select>

<div id=”adjust”>
    <input type=”text” value=”choise3”></input>
    <input type=”text” value=”choise4”></input>
</div>

</form>
```

When a user makes a choice in #select1 I want to replace te form fields in div #adjust with fields I construct from a query from a database (or a few partial forms). So the fields can be replaced by totally other fields and also more or less fields.

Replacing is no problem with eg. Jquery. But when they are filled, how does Zend form process them in a correct way (because I didn’t define the fields in the form). And when there are fields not passing the validators, how do they get back then with fault announcements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend: Form validation: value was not found in the haystack error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231870/zend-form-validation-value-was-not-found-in-the-haystack-error)

Comment: you will disable in_array validation and will validate that field manual or you will write a new validator which will handle both possibilities.

checkout this question to disable in_array validation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248482/how-to-disable-inarray-validator-forms-in-zend-framework2

Comment: oh, and third way: you will check post values before form valdation, populate select's option_values for dependency' value, then validate form.